# Multi tab wpf project with RadPaneGroup

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm using RadPaneGroup  in my wpf project to have multi tab RadDocumentPane, and I'm using Telerik Rad component, and when I using this code:
RadPaneGroup.Items.Refresh(); 
all of open tabs closed automatically.
has any one experience about using RadPaneGroup  and RadDocumentPane in wpf?
Thank you for quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

What are trying to do? 
I am assuming you are trying to refresh something,

in which case you may need to supply the index of the item you are trying to refresh ... Like this

```
RadPaneGroup.Items[0].Refresh;
```

0 here is the counter or the item number you are trying to refersh also took out () from refresh.

Hope this helped!!

Comment: RadPaneGroup.Items(0).Refresh() this code has an syntax error.

Comment: Error 20 Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.Items' cannot be used like a method

Comment: Ive edited the answer for you. Try the new code , it formatted to suit c#.